# Use SQL Statement in access 2007

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vb6

How to use SQL Statement in access

I'm using visual basic 6.0

```
SELECT x, y FROM table_a
MINUS
SELECT x, y FROM table_b;
```

My Visual basic code is this

```
Adodc1.RecordSource ="SELECT Sum((Quantity)*12) FROM Sell_Detail Where Cateogry='Large'"
Minus
"Select Sum(No_Of_Bottle) FROM Add_Bottle Where Cateogry='Large'"
```

Comment: I removed it and it is by mistake Thanks

Comment: Please do not keep posting the same question, see the reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892124/store-two-queries-result-in-third-variable

Comment: ok I'll pay attention next time, help me how to ask question to a particular person because when I comment it goes to all.....Thanks

Comment: Any comment can be viewed by everyone, but if you want to make a particular person notice, you can use @ for example @remou would be posted to me.

Comment: This, [Subtract two Queries Result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21875072/588306), [Store two Queries result in third variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21892124/588306), and [Using Adodc control to subtract Queries Result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21908078/588306) are all the same question.