# Using Adodc control to subtract Queries Result

Tags: database, vb6

I'm still not able to understand why it is not work

### =>>what I try

I try to Use adodb,Dao    control
but I'm not satisfy Because I Don't know about ADODB,DAO and
my remaining application using adodc control so if I Use Other Control it make's mess

### =>>Code

```
Dim large_tbl As String 
Dim sell_large As String


large_tbl = "SELECT Sum(No_Of_Bottle) FROM add_cotton where Cateogry='Large'"
sell_large = "SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM Sell_Detail where Cateogry='Large'"

Adodc1.RecordSource = large_tbl - sell_large
Adodc1.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: You are right but I can't get the idea how to do it that is why I'm asking again and agian

Comment: Then please comment on the existing answers you've been given. Repeating the question won't help.

Comment: This, [Subtract two Queries Result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21875072/588306), [Store two Queries result in third variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21892124/588306), and [Use SQL Statement in access 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21892646/588306) are all the same question.